# how to fix java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, web-services, arraylist

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index:
>   0, Size: 0 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)

in line of arraylist.java

```
private void rangeCheck(int index) {
    if (index >= size)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(outOfBoundsMsg(index));
}
```

in line

```
List lstpp = getResult(pp) ;
    System.out.println("=====Persegi Panjang====");
    System.out.println("luas = "+((Integer)lstpp.get(0)));
```

Please help

Comment: index > size should do

Comment: @ay89 that is java library code you are criticizing.

Comment: try to find problem in `getResult` method.

Comment: All the information you need is in this question.. the answers arent going to be able to provide any breakthroughs, perhaps you can read the question once and you should get it.

Comment: @ay89 false. That would just make things entirely wrong... Think about that again.

Comment: @KarthikT umm.. no, threw just a solution in general. haven't noticed the context.

Comment: @ay89 no, you just wrote random garbage without reading. And it is **not a solution**. With or without context...

Comment: @ppeterka66 see the answer of whoAmI, its exactly the same, except of the context of ArrayList.java.

Comment: @ay89 your answer `index>size would do` is still **garbage, false, and misleading**, no matter who you refer to. **Also, if you could read properly what zou referenced, you'd notice the relation operator to be the _other way round_...** Show some respect, and admit your own faults. That is crucial in professional environments. Sorry for shouting, but spreading so obviously bad information, and trying to defend it so fiercely brings out the animal from me.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 6):

You want to get an element from an empty array. That's why the `Size: 0` from the exception

`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0`

So you cant do `lstpp.get(0)` until you fill the array.

Answer (score 5):

`lstpp` is empty. You cant access the first element of an empty list.

In general, you can check if `size > index`.

In your case, you need to check if `lstpp` is empty. (you can use `!lstpp.isEmpty()`)

Answer (score 2):

You do not have any elements in the list so can't access the first element.

Answer (score 2):

```
for ( int i=0 ; i<=list.size() ; i++){
....}
```

By executing this for loop , the loop will execute with a thrown exception as `IndexOutOfBoundException` cause, suppose list size is 10 , so when index i will get to 10 i.e when i=10 the exception will be thrown cause `index=size`, i.e. `i=size` and as known that Java considers index starting from 0,1,2...etc the expression which Java agrees upon is `index < size`. So the solution for such exception is to make the statement in loop as `i<list.size()`

```
for ( int i=0 ; i<list.size() ; i++){
...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the first element `lstpp.get(0)` of an empty array. Just add an element to your array and check for `!lstpp.isEmpty()` before accessing an element

Answer (score 0):

This error happens because your list `lstpp` is empty (Nothing at index 0). So either there is a bug in your `getResult()` function, or the empty list is normal and you need to handle this case (By checking the size of the list before, or catching the exception).

Comment: Thanks sir, i've found the trouble is in the getResult() function, forget to change the "Return null" to "return (the variable)". *I'm a java beginner* xoxo

Answer (score 0):

Use `if(index.length() < 0)`  for Integer

or

Use `if(index.equals(null)` for String