# what is the reason of this ? java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing, play-billing-library

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:
>
> at java.util.ArrayList.get (ArrayList.java:411)
>
> at salavat.mahammad.xxx.salavat.ayarlar$10.onSkuDetailsResponse$32ef7931 (ayarlar.java)
>
> at com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientImpl$10$1.run (BillingClientImpl.java)
>
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:836)
>
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:103)
>
> at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:203)
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6251)
>
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
>
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1073)
>
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:934)

Comment: Check this [how to fix java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18823792/how-to-fix-java-lang-indexoutofboundsexception)

Comment: To get a proper answer you need to add more information to your question. Please add the code that throws this exception

Comment: Did you find out why this is happening? I've got the same issue. It happens once in a hundred times, but then I'm losing out valuable paying app users :(